# Can I select a random row based on sub ID using sqldf?

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
> mydata
ID ID2 ID3 X1 X2
1  1    1
2  2    1
3  3    1
4  1    2
5  2    2
6  1    3
7  2    3
8  3    3
9  4    3
10 1    4
11 2    4
```

I want to take a random row(random ID2) for each `ID3`, so I can have a new database like this:

```
> mydata2
ID ID2 ID3 X1 X2
1   3    1
2   2    2
3   3    3
4   1    4
```

Can I do this in `sqldf`? Or other code?

Answer (score 2):

With sqldf:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select max(random(*)) r, * from mydata group by ID3")
```

Answer (score 0):

"Or other code", using `apply`:

```
#dummy data
df <- read.table(text="ID ID2 ID3
1  1    1
2  2    1
3  3    1
4  1    2
5  2    2
6  1    3
7  2    3
8  3    3
9  4    3
10 1    4
11 2    4",header=TRUE)

#using lapply
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(split.data.frame(df,df$ID3),
               function(d) d[sample(1:nrow(d),1),]))
```